# Closed form for ${\large\int}_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{\sqrt{1-x+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I want to find a closed form for this integral:
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx\tag1$$
*Mathematica* and *Maple* cannot evaluate it directly, and I was not able to find it in tables. A numeric approximation for it is
$$I\approx2.100290124838430655413586565140170651784798511276914224...\tag2$$
(click [here](http://goo.gl/Sc8x3I) to see more digits).

*Mathematica* is able to find a closed form for a parameterized integral in terms of the [Appell hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x^a}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx\\=\frac1{a+1}F_1\left(a+1;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};a+2;(-1)^{\small1/3},-(-1)^{\small2/3}\right).\tag3$$
I suspect this expression could be rewritten in a simpler form, but I could not find it yet.

It's easy to see that $I=I''(0),$ but it's unclear how to find a closed-form derivative of the Appell hypergeometric function with respect to its parameters.

Could you help me to find a closed form for $I$?

---

*Update:* Numerical calculations suggest that for all complex $z$ with $\Re(z)>0$ the following functional equation holds:
$$z\,I(z-1)-\!\left(z+\tfrac12\right)\,I(z)+(z+1)\,I(z+1)=1.\tag4$$

Comment: It can be rewritten as $~\displaystyle\int_{-\frac\pi6}^\frac\pi6\bigg(\ln\frac{\sqrt3~\tan x+1}2\bigg)^2\frac{dx}{\cos x}.~$

Comment: Another equivalent form of the integral is $\displaystyle I=\frac8\pi\Re{\large\int}_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3\!\left(\frac12\left(1-x \sqrt{-3}\right)\right)}{\left(1-x\sqrt{-3}\right)\,\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.$

Comment: This looks promising or perhaps not:
$$
2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+2t}\right)}{1+2t}\ dt.
$$

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Edited for a more concise derivation:**

Define $\mathcal{I}$ to be the value of the definite integral,

> $$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{1}$$

The definite integral $\mathcal{I}$ is found to have as an approximate numerical value

$$\mathcal{I}\approx2.10029.\tag{2}$$

---

We begin by transforming the integral via an [Euler substitution of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#The_first_substitution_of_Euler):

$$\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}=x+t\implies x=\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+2t},\tag{3}$$

$$\implies\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\left(-2\right)\left(1+t+t^{2}\right)}{\left(1+2t\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$

$$\implies\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}=\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+2t}+t=\frac{1+t+t^{2}}{1+2t}.$$

Under the transformation $(3)$, the integral $\mathcal{I}$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+2t}\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}=x+t\right]}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left[\ln{\left(1-t\right)}+\ln{\left(1+t\right)}-\ln{\left(1+2t\right)}\right]^{2}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t.\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

Next, using the algebraic identity

$$\left(a+b-c\right)^{2}=a^{2}+2b^{2}-\left(a-b\right)^{2}+\left(a-c\right)^{2}-2bc,$$

with $a=\ln{\left(1-t\right)}\land b=\ln{\left(1+t\right)}\land c=\ln{\left(1+2t\right)}$, we may expand the integral $\mathcal{I}$ as a sum of five simpler logarithmic integrals:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left[\ln{\left(1-t\right)}+\ln{\left(1+t\right)}-\ln{\left(1+2t\right)}\right]^{2}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t+4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1+t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left[\ln{\left(1-t\right)}-\ln{\left(1+t\right)}\right]^{2}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left[\ln{\left(1-t\right)}-\ln{\left(1+2t\right)}\right]^{2}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&~~~~~-4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+t\right)}\ln{\left(1+2t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t+4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1+t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t+2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+2t}\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&~~~~~-4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+t\right)}\ln{\left(1+2t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t.\tag{5}\\
\end{align}$$

Now, we'll find it convenient to introduce the following two auxiliary functions:

$$J{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(y\right)}}{1+zy}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{z\ge-1},\tag{6a}$$

and

$$H{\left(a,c\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1+ay\right)}}{1+cy}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{a\ge-1\land c>-1}.\tag{6b}$$

As we shall see, the integral $\mathcal{I}$ can be expressed entirely in terms of the auxiliary functions $J$ and $H$, and hence, entirely in terms of elementary functions and the standard polylogarithms:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t+4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1+t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t+2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+2t}\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{4\ln{\left(1+t\right)}\ln{\left(1+2t\right)}}{1+2t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(u\right)}}{3-2u}\,\mathrm{d}u;~~~\small{\left[1-t=u\right]}\\
&~~~~~+4\,H{\left(1,2\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{4\ln^{2}{\left(v\right)}}{\left(3-v\right)\left(1+v\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v;~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-t}{1+t}=v\right]}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(w\right)}}{1+2w}\,\mathrm{d}w;~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-t}{1+2t}=w\right]}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\left(\left[\ln{\left(1+t\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1+2t\right)}\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1+2t\right)}}{1+t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)};~~~\small{I.B.P.s}\\
&=\frac23\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(u\right)}}{1-\frac23u}\,\mathrm{d}u+4\,H{\left(1,2\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac13\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(v\right)}}{1-\frac13v}\,\mathrm{d}v-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(v\right)}}{1+v}\,\mathrm{d}v+2\,J{\left(2\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{(2)}\ln^{2}{(3)}+H{\left(2,1\right)}\\
&=\frac23\,J{\left(-\frac23\right)}+4\,H{\left(1,2\right)}-\frac13\,J{\left(-\frac13\right)}\\
&~~~~~-J{\left(1\right)}+2\,J{\left(2\right)}-\ln{(2)}\ln^{2}{(3)}+H{\left(2,1\right)}.\tag{7}\\
\end{align}$$

The function $H$ can be expressed in terms of $J$, dilogarithms, and elementary functions. Define $\gamma:=\frac{a-c}{c}$. For $0<a\land0<c$, we have $-1<\gamma$ and

$$\begin{align}
H{\left(a,c\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1+ay\right)}}{1+cy}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{\frac{1}{1+a}}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{x\left[c+\left(a-c\right)x\right]}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{\left[\frac{1}{1+ay}=x\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\int_{\frac{1}{1+a}}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{a-c}{c}\int_{\frac{1}{1+a}}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{c+\left(a-c\right)x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\frac{a-c}{c^{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{1+a}}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\frac{\gamma}{c}\int_{\frac{1}{1+a}}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{1+\gamma x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\frac{\gamma}{c}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{1+\gamma x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\gamma}{c}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{1+a}}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}}{1+\gamma x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\frac{\gamma}{c}J{\left(\gamma\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\gamma}{c\left(1+a\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{w}{1+a}\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)w}\,\mathrm{d}w;~~~\small{\left[\left(1+a\right)x=w\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\left(\frac{a-c}{c^{2}}\right)J{\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\small{+\frac{\gamma}{c\left(1+a\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(w\right)}-2\ln{\left(w\right)}\ln{\left(1+a\right)}+\ln^{2}{\left(1+a\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)w}\,\mathrm{d}w}\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\left(\frac{a-c}{c^{2}}\right)J{\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\gamma}{c\left(1+a\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(w\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)w}\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&~~~~~-\frac{2}{c}\ln{\left(1+a\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)\ln{\left(w\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)w}\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{c}\ln^{2}{\left(1+a\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)w}\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\left(\frac{a-c}{c^{2}}\right)J{\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\gamma}{c\left(1+a\right)}\,J{\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2}{c}\ln{\left(1+a\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)w\right)}}{w}\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{c}\ln^{2}{\left(1+a\right)}\ln{\left(1+\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}-\left(\frac{a-c}{c^{2}}\right)J{\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{a-c}{c^{2}\left(1+a\right)}\,J{\left(\frac{a-c}{c\left(1+a\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{2}{c}\ln{\left(1+a\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\left(\frac{\gamma}{1+a}\right)\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{c}\ln^{2}{\left(1+a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{a\left(1+c\right)}{\left(1+a\right)c}\right)}\\
&=\frac{a-c}{c^{2}\left(1+a\right)}\,J{\left(\frac{a-c}{c\left(1+a\right)}\right)}-\frac{a-c}{c^{2}}\,J{\left(\frac{a-c}{c}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{2}{c}\ln{\left(1+a\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{c-a}{c\left(1+a\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{3c}\ln^{3}{\left(1+a\right)}+\frac{1}{c}\ln^{2}{\left(1+a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{a\left(1+c\right)}{\left(1+a\right)c}\right)}.\tag{8}\\
\end{align}$$

The function $J$ reduces to the trilogarithm. For $-1\le z\land z\neq0$,

$$\begin{align}
J{\left(z\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(y\right)}}{1+zy}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\frac{2}{z}\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-z\right)}.\tag{9}\\
\end{align}$$

Thus, continuing from where we left off at the last line of $(7)$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\frac23\,J{\left(-\frac23\right)}-\frac13\,J{\left(-\frac13\right)}-J{\left(1\right)}+2\,J{\left(2\right)}\\
&~~~~~+4\,H{\left(1,2\right)}+H{\left(2,1\right)}-\ln{(2)}\ln^{2}{(3)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac23\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac13\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-1\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-2\right)}\\
&~~~~~\small{+4\left[-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac14\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac12\right)}-\ln{(2)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac14\right)}-\frac56\ln^{3}{(2)}+\frac12\ln^{2}{(2)}\ln{(3)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~\small{+\left[2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-1\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-\frac13\right)}-\ln{(9)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac13\right)}-\frac23\ln^{3}{(3)}+\ln{(4)}\ln^{2}{(3)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{(2)}\ln^{2}{(3)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac23\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac13\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-\frac13\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-2\right)}\\
&~~~~~-4\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac14\right)}+4\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac12\right)}+4\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-1\right)}\\
&~~~~~-4\ln{(2)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac14\right)}-2\ln{(3)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac13\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{10}{3}\ln^{3}{(2)}+2\ln^{2}{(2)}\ln{(3)}+\ln{(2)}\ln^{2}{(3)}-\frac23\ln^{3}{(3)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

For $z\notin[1,\infty)$,

$$\small{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(z\right)}=-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(1-z\right)}+\frac{\ln^3{\left(1-z\right)}}{6}-\frac{\ln{\left(z\right)}\ln^2{\left(1-z\right)}}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}+\zeta{(3)}}.$$

For $0<z<1$,

$$\small{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(z\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(1-z\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)}=\frac{\ln^3{\left(1-z\right)}}{6}-\frac{\ln{\left(z\right)}\ln^2{\left(1-z\right)}}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln{\left(1-z\right)}+\zeta{(3)}}.$$

Setting $z=\frac13$,

$$\small{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac13\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac23\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-\frac12\right)}=\frac{\ln^3{\left(\frac23\right)}}{6}-\frac{\ln{\left(\frac13\right)}\ln^2{\left(\frac23\right)}}{2}+\zeta{(2)}\ln{\left(\frac23\right)}+\zeta{(3)}}.$$

$$\small{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac13\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac23\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-\frac12\right)}=\frac{\ln^{3}{(2)}-3\ln{(2)}\ln^{2}{(3)}+2\ln^{3}{(3)}}{6}+\zeta{(2)}\ln{\left(\frac23\right)}+\zeta{(3)}}$$

$$\small{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac13\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(\frac23\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-\frac12\right)}=\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(\frac32\right)}\ln{\left(18\right)}}{6}-\zeta{(2)}\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}+\zeta{(3)}}$$

---

Comment: *Go David!* +1! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Go you for spotting the simplification brought on by the Euler substitution! It seems that was really the key insight for this problem.

Comment: I've to make a confession to you David, truth be told I've already had an idea to answer this OP since I posted my comment (I made my current answer two days ago) but I resisted to answer it and I plant to answer it when this is a bounty question. :P

Comment: @DavidH Good job! Do you use both $:=$ and $=:$ to denote an equality by definition?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yes. I use $:=$ to define symbols, and I use $=:$ to label expressions. Also, before you compliment my answer I should warn you I'm having more trouble finishing it than I expected. Evaluating $I_4$ is turning out to be very difficult... :/

Comment: David, if you allow me to assist in evaluating $I_4$, you may refer to my **ADDENDUM** in my edited answer.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Your assistance is certainly appreciated, and I'm a little miffed I didn't notice that myself! I've been busy this week, but I finally got around to applying your suggestion and completing my answer. While it is numerically correct, I haven't yet verified it to be equivalent to Cleo's value. But this is probably just a matter of using the right polylog identities. TBC...

Comment: Good Job. [Here is another one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932888/closed-form-for-large-int-01-frac-ln-colormagenta3x-sqrtx2-x1d).

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Cleo's answer confirmed! =D

Comment: Like Tunk-Fey said in his answer, your calculation of $I_1,\cdots,I_6$ can be shortened by using his technique and equation $(5)$

Answer (score 43):

$$I=12\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac13\right)+20\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac23\right)+\frac{32}3\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac23\right)\ln3+\left(4\ln2+\frac{10}{3}\ln3\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac34\right)\\-\frac{163}6\zeta(3)+8\ln^32+\frac23\ln^22\cdot\ln3-\frac23\ln2\cdot\ln^23-\frac{7\pi^2}3\ln2+\frac{11\pi^2}{9}\ln3.$$

Answer (score 16):

I have *an answer*, but it is somewhat too lengthy and messy so I use Wolfram Alpha to help me out. First we use Euler substitution by setting $t+x=\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$, then we have
$$
x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+2t}\qquad\color{red}{\Rightarrow}\qquad dx=-\frac{2(1+t+t^2)}{(1+2t)^2}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{x^2-x+1}=\frac{1+t+t^2}{1+2t}.
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx&=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+2t}\right)}{1+2t}\ dt\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\bigg[\ln(1-t)+\ln(1+t)-\ln(1+2t)\bigg]^2}{1+2t}\ dt.\tag1
\end{align}
Set $u=1+2t\ \color{red}{\Rightarrow}\ t=\dfrac{1+u}{2}$ and expand the integrand, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\bigg[\ln\left(\frac{3-u}{2}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{1+u}{2}\right)-\ln u\bigg]^2}u&=\frac{\bigg[\ln3-2\ln2+\ln\left(1-\frac{u}{3}\right)+\ln\left(1+u\right)-\ln u\bigg]^2}u
\end{align}
Let from this part [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%28ln%283%29-2*ln%282%29%2Bln%281-u%2F3%29%2Bln%281%2Bu%29-ln%28u%29%29%5E2%5D%2Fu) takes over since it is very cumbersome and complicated, the integrand turns out to be

[image]

It *seems* none of the integrand are difficult to integrate it term-wise, either by substitution, IBP multiple times, or series expansion, but of course it would be tedious so let [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28ln%283%29%2Bln%281-u%2F3%29-2*ln%282%29%2Bln%281%2Bu%29-ln%28u%29%29%5E2%2Fu) do it. Let the expanded form of integrand be $f(u)$, then $(1)$ becomes
$$
I=\int_1^3 f(u)\ du\tag2
$$
and the indefinite integral of $(2)$ is

[image]

Unfortunately, Wolfram Alpha fails to give an answer like @Cleo's after substituting the limits of integration. Perhaps, *Mathematica* or *Maple* is able to give the closed-form. I hope David H can complete his answer and can prove @Cleo's claim. *Wish him luck!!*

---

**ADDENDUM :**

I hope David H allow me to assist in the evaluation of $\color{blue}{I_4}$, *of course he will take all the credit for evaluating this problem since he has done the biggest part of the calculation*.

Consider
\begin{align}
J=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+2t}\ln^2\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\ dt.
\end{align}
It's easy to see that
\begin{align}
J&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-t)}{1+2t}\ dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{1+2t}\ dt-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)\ln(1+t)}{1+2t}\ dt\\
&=\color{red}{I_1}+\color{green}{I_2}-2\color{blue}{I_4}.\tag3
\end{align}
To evaluate $J$, let $u=\dfrac{1-t}{1+t}$ then we have
$$
t=\frac{1-u}{1+u}\quad ,\ 1+2t=\frac{3-u}{1+u}\ ,\quad\text{and}\quad dt=-\frac{4}{(1+u)^2}\ du.
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
J&=4\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2u}{(3-u)(1+u)}\ dt\\
&={\large\int_0^1}\left[\frac{\ln^2u}{u+1}-\frac{\ln^2u}{u-3}\right]\ du\tag4
\end{align}
where it is easy to prove that
$$
\int\frac{\ln^2x}{x+a}\ dx=2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac xa\right)\ln x-2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac xa\right)+\ln\left(\frac{x+a}a\right)\ln^2x+C.\tag5
$$
The rest part is just technical matter and I leave it to David. Note that, the similar technique can be used to evaluate $I_5$ and $I_6$ in his calculation.

Comment: Are you user Cleo?

Comment: @Venus No. Why did you think so?

Answer (score 9):

I have not been either to find a closed form expression for this integral; so forgive me if what I send you is of no interest.

What I did is to expand the denominator as a Taylor series at $x=0$, which gives $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{7 x^3}{16}-\frac{37 x^4}{128}+\frac{23
   x^5}{256}+\frac{331 x^6}{1024}+\frac{457 x^7}{2048}-\frac{2413
   x^8}{32768}-\frac{17557 x^9}{65536}-\frac{49343
   x^{10}}{262144}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ and take into account the fact that $$\int x^n\log^2(x)dx=\frac{x^{n+1} \left((n+1)^2 \log ^2(x)-2 (n+1) \log (x)+2\right)}{(n+1)^3}$$ which implies $$\int_0^1 x^n\log^2(x)dx=\frac{2}{(n+1)^3}$$ Using the coefficients, the summation does not seem to converge very fast.

**Added later**

In a comment to my answer, Vladimir Reshetnikov pointed out that the coefficients of the Taylor series are just $P_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ (what I totally missed). So, as an infinite series, the result is $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx\tag1=2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{P_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) }{(n+1)^3}$$ for which I did not find any closed form and which has a very slow convergence (adding $10,000$ terms leads to $\simeq 2.100290124838414$).

Comment: The coefficients of the Taylor series are values of the [Legendre polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html) $P_n\left(\tfrac12\right).$

Comment: Sorry for the typo; I fixed it. So, do you then have the expression as an infinite series ?

Comment: Yes, I even have a polynomial recurrence relation for its partial sums. But it's still not clear how to find a closed form for the infinite series.

Comment: Note that ${1 \over \sqrt{1 - 2th + h^{2}}} = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}h^{\ell}{\rm P}_{\ell}\left(\,t\,\right)$. With $t = 1/2$ and $h = x$ you have a nice expansion in Legendre Polynomia.