# Integral of Combination Log and Inverse Trig Function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

Does the following integral have a closed-form ?:

> \begin{equation}
> \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\left(\,x\,\right) \over 1 + x}\,\arccos\left(\,x\,\right)
> \,{\rm d}x
> \end{equation}

This integral has been posted in [Integral and Series](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic459.html) a week ago but it remains unsolved. So, I decide to post it here.

Could anyone here please help me to find the closed-form preferably with elementary ways ( high school methods ) ?.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have not been able (even with a CAS) to find any closed form. Developing the integrand as a Taylor series built at $x=0$, the element are quite simple and the result is of the form $\frac{a-b\pi}{c}$, where $a,b,c$ are positive integers. However the convergence is apparently quite slow.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Could you please provide me 50 digits of its numeric value using CAS? Thank you (✿◠‿◠)

Comment: $-1.105949707389000117772047743618712561526950639110945$.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Lucian. By the way, do you know how to get more digits of the numeric result of certain integral in Wolfram Alpha? What is the code or input?

Comment: Try $N[\ldots,50]$.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but what if you express the inverse cosine in terms of logarithms and complex numbers? According to Wikipedia, we have $\arccos{(x)} = i\ln{(x - i\sqrt{1 - x^2})}$

Comment: @GeorgeDaccache It's still hard for me, but thanks for your hint

Comment: Integrating by parts once gives the equivalent, $I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{(-x)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{x}\ln{(x+1)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$. This is probably the best thing to do first. After that, you can perform an Euler substitution to get rid of the radical.

Comment: I'm waiting your answer @DavidH (ô‿ô)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova I was able to reduce the integral to $\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln^2(\cos x)\,dx$, which you asked about in another question. Has a closed form for that integral been found yet?

Comment: @DavidH Yes, it has. Mr. RV has answered that OP and I've awarded him 100 rep bounty

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, we set $x=\cos\theta\ \color{red}{\Rightarrow}\ dx=-\sin\theta\ d\theta$, then
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\arccos(x)\ dx=-\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}\cdot\theta\ \ln (\cos\theta)\ d\theta.\tag1
\end{align}
Using the fact that
\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac\theta2\right)=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}
\end{align}
and setting $y=\frac\theta2$, then $(1)$ turns out to be
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}=-\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}2}\theta\tan\left(\frac\theta2\right)\ln (\cos\theta)\ d\theta=-4\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}y\tan\left(y\right)\ln (\cos2y)\ dy.\tag2
\end{align}
Now, setting $t=\tan y\ \color{red}{\Rightarrow}\ dy=\dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}$ yields
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}&=-4\int_0^1 t\arctan(t)\ln \left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)\ \frac{dt}{1+t^2}\\
&=4\int_0^1\left[ \frac{t\arctan(t)}{1+t^2}\ln \left(1+t^2\right)- \frac{t\arctan(t)}{1+t^2}\ln \left(1-t^2\right)\right]\ dt.\tag3
\end{align}
Actually, the second integral in $(3)$ has been evaluated by Kirill and it is equal to
[\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{t\arctan(t)}{1+t^2}\ln \left(1-t^2\right)\ dt=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac{\pi}{8}\log^2 2 +\text{G}\log 2,\tag4
\end{align}](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/556505/123277)
where $\text{G}$ is is the [Catalan's Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html). We may also refer to [the following technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921153/123277) to evaluate
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+at\right)\ln \left(1+bt\right)}{1+ct}\ dt.
\end{align}
The first integral in $(3)$ can be evaluated by setting $t=\tan x$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{t\arctan(t)}{1+t^2}\ln \left(1+t^2\right)\ dt=-2\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}x\tan x\ln (\cos x)\ dx.
\end{align}
Now, applying IBP by setting $u=x$ and
$$
v=\int\tan x\ln (\cos x)\ dx=-\ln^2(\cos x)\quad \color{red}{\Rightarrow}\quad \text{set}\ z= \cos x.
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{t\arctan(t)}{1+t^2}\ln \left(1+t^2\right)\ dt&=2x\ln^2(\cos x)\bigg|_{x=0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}-2\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\ln^2 (\cos x)\ dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}8\ln^22-2\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\ln^2 (\cos x)\ dx.\tag5
\end{align}
Random Variable has successfully proven that
[$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\ln^2 (\sin x)\ dx=\frac{\pi^{3}}{192} + \frac{\text{G}}{2}\ln2 + \frac{3 \pi}{16} \ln^{2}2 - \Im \  \text{Li}_{3}(1-i)\tag6
$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/920224/123277)
and Lucian has shown that
[$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\ln^2 (\sin x)\ dx+\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\ln^2 (\cos x)\ dx=\frac{\pi^3}{24}+\dfrac\pi2\ln^22.\tag7
$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/917589/123277)
Then by using $(3)$, $(4)$, $(5)$, $(6)$, and $(7)$, we finally obtain

> \begin{align}
> \mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\arccos(x)\ dx=\color{purple}{2\text{G}\ln2+\frac\pi2\ln^22+\frac{\pi^3}{16}+4\,\Im\bigg[\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)\bigg]}.
> \end{align}

The above result is exactly similar to Cleo's answer. It can be proven by using the following trilogarithm identity

$\displaystyle
\operatorname{Li}_3(z)+\operatorname{Li}_3(1-z)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-\frac1z\right)=\zeta(3)+\frac16\ln^3z+\zeta(2)\ln z-\frac12\ln^2z\ln(1-z).
$$\tag8$

Setting $z=i$ to $(8)$, Wolfram Alpha shows that $\displaystyle\Im\bigg[\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)\bigg]=-\Im\bigg[\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i)\bigg]$ since
[$$
\Im\bigg[\zeta(3)+\frac16\ln^3(i)+\zeta(2)\ln(i)-\frac12\ln^2(i)\ln(1-i)-\operatorname{Li}_3(i)\bigg]=0.
$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Imaginary+part%28%5Czeta%283%29%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B6%7D%5Cln%5E3%28z%29%2B%5Czeta%282%29%5Cln%28z%29-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cln%5E2%28z%29%5Cln%281-z%29-%28polylog%5B3%2Cz%5D%29%29%2C+z%3Di)
Thus, the another closed-form of $\mathcal{I}$ is

> \begin{align}
> \mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\arccos(x)\ dx=\color{purple}{2\text{G}\ln2+\frac\pi2\ln^22+\frac{\pi^3}{16}-4\,\Im\bigg[\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i)\bigg]}.
> \end{align}

Comment: *I am very lucky to be able to find the closed-form of this integral*

Comment: Wow! Finally, someone with proof. Cool! +1 Mr. Tunk-Fey. Thanks for your answer. It takes time for me to study your answer specially Mr. Kirill's answer (✿◠‿◠)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Tunk-Fey. I give you +175 rep. Congrats! (>‿◠)✌

Answer (score 22):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\cdot\arccos x}{1+x}\,dx=2\,G\ln2+\frac\pi2\ln^22+\frac{\pi^3}{16}-4\,\Im\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i).$$
You also can have a different form that does not use complex numbers:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\cdot\arccos x}{1+x}\,dx=2\,G\ln2+\frac\pi4\ln^22-\frac{\pi^3}8+{_4F_3}\!\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,1\\\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\,1\right)\!.$$

Answer (score 5):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932651/153012) an other possible solution is

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\arccos(x)\,dx\, = 2\,G\ln2 + \frac{\pi}{8}\ln^2 2-\frac{5\pi^3}{32} + 4 \, \Im \left[ \operatorname{Li}_3 \left( \frac{1+i}{2} \right) \right].$$

From here we can only give something more, if we find an answer for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918680/153012). I think without something really new method we don't have chance to answer it. Maybe if I get some surprising answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/932932/153012) at complex arguments, then we can go further, but I really don't have hope.

Comment: Thank you for giving me another form of closed-form. +1