# Closed-form of $\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, polylogarithm

I'm looking for a closed form of this integral.

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx ,$$

where $\operatorname{Li}_2$ is the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

A numerical approximation of it is

$$ I \approx 1.39130720750676668181096483812551383015419528634319581297153...$$

As Lucian said $I$ has the following equivalent forms:

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( \sqrt{x} \right)}{2 \, \sqrt{x} \, \sqrt{1-x}} \,dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \operatorname{Li}_2(\sin x) \, dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \operatorname{Li}_2(\cos x) \, dx$$

According to *Mathematica* it has a closed-form in terms of generalized hypergeometric function, Claude Leibovici has given us [this form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/937926/153012).

With *Maple* using Anastasiya-Romanova's form I could get a closed-form in term of Meijer G function. It was similar to Juan Ospina's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938024/153012), but it wasn't exactly that form. I also don't know that his form is correct, or not, because the numerical approximation has just $6$ correct digits.

I'm looking for a closed form of $I$ without using generalized hypergeometric function, Meijer G function or $\operatorname{Li}_2$ or $\operatorname{Li}_3$.

I hope it exists. Similar integrals are the following.

$$\begin{align}
J_1 & = \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{1+x} \,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \ln 2 - \frac58 \zeta(3) \\
J_2 & = \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-x}} \,dx = \pi^2 - 8 \end{align}$$

Related techniques are in [this](http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Papers/ArXiv/Zeta21/polylog.pdf) or in [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.6229.pdf) paper. [This](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/Livres/Connon%20some%20series%20and%20integrals/Vol-3.pdf) one also could be useful.

Comment: $I=\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\text{Li}_2(\sin x)dx=\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\text{Li}_2(\cos x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$.

Comment: Okay, we have answers using CAS & Maple. After that what? Using Mathematica? May I post my answer using Wolfram Alpha? The best I can get is $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^k x\,dx$$

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova FYI, the integral in your series can easily be evaluated in terms of the beta function. ^_^

Comment: @DavidH Yeah, you're right. Using Wiki notation we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^k x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\text{B}\left(\frac{k+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right)}{k^2}$$

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova After that, I believe the way to go is to split the sum into even and odd $k$. The even sum at least as a very nice and succinct closed form, so the problem boils down to summing the odd terms.

Comment: I've only now noticed it: How odd that you have asked this question exactly on my birthday. :-)

Comment: @Lucian For now I have some more partial answers for the closed form of $\Im\left[\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right]$. Maybe later I will update my answer there with all of these additional informations. Happy b-day, in hindsight.

Comment: What I have obtained so far is $$ I = \frac{\pi^3}{6} - \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{8x}{x^4 - 1} \Im \left\{ \log^{2} \left( \frac{1+ix}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right\} \, dx. $$ I have no idea where this will lead us, though.

Comment: @sos440 Are you sure? For me the numerical value of your $I$ is $-5.605568137$ which is different from the original problem.

Comment: @user153012, I am pretty sure both from my calculation and from a numerical verification by *Mathematica 8.0*. You should get $I = 1.39130720750676668..$

Comment: @sos440 Interesting. *Mathematica* gives $1.3913$, but *Maple* gives $-5.6056$.

Comment: @user153012, If the branch cut is the source of the problem, replacing imaginary part by $\arctan x \log(\frac{1}{2}(1+x^2))$ may fix that, I guess...

Comment: @sos440 The same $-5.6056$ result with the $\arctan x \log(\frac{1}{2}(1+x^2))$ replacement.

Comment: @user153012, Quite strange... I got the same result $1.39131...$ from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Pi%5E3%2F6+-+Integrate%5B8x+ArcTan%5Bx%5D+Log%5B%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2F2%5D+%2F+%28x%5E4-1%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+1%2C+Infinity%7D%5D). Is it mean that Wolfram and Maple are adopting completely different algorithm for this...?

Comment: @sos440 Maybe I'm wrong, but I have the feeling that Wolfram is incorrect.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

We will go through a sequence of integrals, and, remarkably, we will see that at each step an integrand will have a continuous closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions, dilogarithms and trilogarithms, so evaluation of an integral is then just a matter of calculating values (or limits) at end-points and taking a difference.

I used *Mathematica* to help me find some of those antiderivatives, but then I significantly simplified them manually. In each case correctness of the result was proved manually by direct differentiation, so we do not have to trust *Mathematica* on it. Maybe somebody will find a more elegant and enlightening way to evaluate them.

---

First change the variable $x=\cos\theta$ and rewrite the integral as:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\operatorname{Li}_2(\cos\theta)\,d\theta\tag{0}$$
Then we use a [known integral representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.07.07.0003.01) of the dilogarithm:
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t\,z)}t\,dt.\tag1$$
Use it to rewrite $(0)$ and then change the order of integration:
$$I=-\int_0^1\frac1t\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1-t\,\cos\theta)\,d\theta\,dt.\tag2$$

---

Our first goal is to evaluate the inner integral in $(2)$. The integrand has a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions and dilogarithms that is continuous in the region of integration:
$$\int\ln(1-t\,\cos\theta)\,d\theta=\theta\!\;\ln\!\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}2\right)-2\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_2\!\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}t\!\;e^{i\!\;\theta}\right).\tag3$$
(compare it with the [raw](http://mathb.in/40064) *Mathematica* result)

Taking the difference of values of $(3)$ at the end-points $\pi/2$ and $0$, we obtain:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1-t\,\cos\theta)\,d\theta=\frac\pi2\,\ln\!\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}2\right)-2\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_2\!\left(i\,\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}t\right).\tag4$$
Recall that the imaginary part of the dilogarithm can be represented as the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html):
$$\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_2(iz)=\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)=\int_0^z\frac{\arctan(v)}v dv.\tag{$4'$}$$
So,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1-t\,\cos\theta)\,d\theta=\frac\pi2\,\ln\!\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}2\right)-2\,\operatorname{Ti}_2\!\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}t\right).\tag{$4''$}$$

---

Now our goal is to evaluate the outer integral in $(2)$. Substituting $(4'')$ back into $(2)$ we get:
$$I=-\frac\pi2\!\;I_1+2\!\;I_2,\tag5$$
where
$$I_1=\int_0^1\frac1t\,\ln\!\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}2\right)dt,\tag6$$
$$I_2=\int_0^1\frac1t\,\operatorname{Ti}_2\!\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}t\right)dt.\tag7$$
The integrand in $(6)$ has a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions and dilogarithms. One way to find it is to change variable $t=2\sqrt{u-u^2}$ and integrate by parts.
$$\int\frac1t\,\ln\!\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}2\right)dt=\frac14\,\ln^2\!\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}2\right)-\frac12\, \operatorname{Li}_2\!\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}2\right).\tag8$$
(compare it with the [raw](http://mathb.in/40065) *Mathematica* result)

Taking the difference of its values at the end-points, and using [well-known values](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) $$\operatorname{Li}_2(1)=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6,\tag{$8'$}$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac12\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\ln^22}2,\tag{$8''$}$$
we get:
$$I_1=\frac{\ln^22}2-\frac{\pi^2}{24}.\tag9$$
To evaluate $I_2$ change the variable $t=\frac{2z}{1+z^2}$:
$$I_2=\int_0^1\frac{1-z^2}{z\,(1+z^2)}\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)\,dz.\tag{10}$$
Again, the integrand has a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions, dilogarithms and trilogarithms. Before giving the result, we will try to split it into smaller parts. First, recall $(4')$ and a simple integral ${\large\int}\frac{1-z^2}{z\,(1+z^2)}dz=\ln\!\left(\frac z{1+z^2}\right)$, and integrate by parts:
$$\int\frac{1-z^2}{z\,(1+z^2)}\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)\,dz=\ln\!\left(\frac z{1+z^2}\right)\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)\\-\underbrace{\int\frac{\ln z\cdot\arctan z}z\,dz}_{I_3}+\underbrace{\int\frac{\ln(1+z^2)\cdot\arctan z}z\,dz}_{I_4}.\tag{11}$$
The following results can be checked by direct differentiation:
$$I_3=\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)\ln z-\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3(iz),\tag{$11'$}$$
$$I_4=\left[\frac{\pi^2}3-\ln\left(1+z^2\right)\ln z-\frac12\,\operatorname{Li}_2\!\left(-z^2\right)\right]\arctan z\\-\frac\pi2\,\arctan^2z+\frac\pi8\,\ln^2\left(1+z^2\right)+\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)\ln\left(1+z^2\right)-2\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3(1+iz).\tag{$11''$}$$
Plugging $(11')$ and $(11'')$ into $(11)$ we obtain:
$$\int\frac{1-z^2}{z\,(1+z^2)}\operatorname{Ti}_2(z)\,dz=\left[\frac{\pi^2}3-\ln\left(1+z^2\right)\ln z-\frac12\,\operatorname{Li}_2\!\left(-z^2\right)\right]\arctan z\\-\frac\pi2\,\arctan^2z+\frac\pi8\,\ln^2\left(1+z^2\right)+\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3(iz)-2\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3(1+iz).\tag{$11'''$}$$
(compare it with the [raw](http://mathb.in/40066) *Mathematica* result)

Taking the difference of its values at the end-points $1$ and $0$, we get:
$$I_2=\frac{3\!\;\pi^3}{32}+\frac\pi8\!\;\ln^22-2\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i).\tag{12}$$
Plugging $(9)$ and $(12)$ back into $(5)$ we get the final result:

> $$\large\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac{5\!\;\pi^3}{24}-4\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i).\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$

Comment: Great! A big (+1)! Looking forward to the final form of solution! :-)

Comment: Definitely this answer deserves the bounty. (+1)

Comment: ***VLADIMIR !!!***

Comment: David H: I recommend that you post yours anyway. It's good when a complicated calculation is replicated independently.

Comment: @DavidH of course it would be nice to see your solution.

Comment: @user153012 I retract my previous statement. I had the same starting point and plan of attacking as Vlad, but he implemented it with far more dexterity than I would have been able to. :)

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist Thank you very much for the bounty!

Comment: Letting $t=\sin2a$ we have $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}2=\cos^2a$, and $\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}t=\tan a$. Also, I think there's a small typo in $(8):$ there should be a *t* rather than a $2$ in the denominator of $\text{Li}_2(\cdot)$.

Comment: @Lucian The formula $(8)$ is correct. Both denominators are $2$. You can verify it by taking a derivative.

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: Thank you all, who worked on this question.

Comment: This is a masterpiece and it might be a solid starting point for investigating about the special values of $\phantom{}_4 F_3$ which can be computed by exploiting the functional identities for the trilogarithm function.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative approach. As shown by *nospoon* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438381),
\begin{equation}\label{shalev} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(x)}{\sqrt{x(1- x\sin^2\theta )}}\,dx = \frac{8}{\sin\theta}\left[\frac{\theta^3}{3}-\text{Im}\,\text{Li}_3\left(1-e^{2i\theta}\right)\right]\tag{1}\end{equation}
holds for any $\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. This is an istance of a very nice principle, according to which every hypergeometric function of the $\phantom{}_{p+1}F_{p}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\ldots;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\ldots;z\right)$ kind has a closed form in terms of polylogarithms. We need to evaluate $\phantom{}_4 F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};1\right)$, hence our arrival point is already pretty close to the statement of $(1)$.

The evaluation of $(1)$ at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ leads to
\begin{equation}\label{shalev2} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(x)}{\sqrt{x(2- x )}}\,dx = 8\left[\frac{\pi^3}{192}-\text{Im}\,\text{Li}_3\left(1-i\right)\right]\tag{2}\end{equation}
and the [functional relations for $\text{Li}_2$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) reduce the original problem to $(2)$. In particular
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\text{Li}_2(\sin\theta)\,d\theta &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1+t^2}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)\,dt\\
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\text{Li}_2(\cos\theta)\,d\theta&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1+t^2}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)\,dt\\ 
&=&\frac{5\pi^3}{24}+4\,\text{Im}\,\text{Li}_3(1-i)\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
as already shown by Reshetnikov.

Answer (score 5):

According to a CAS, $$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left( \sqrt{t} \right)}{2 \, \sqrt{t} \, \sqrt{1-t}} \,dt =\,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};1\right
   )+\frac{\pi ^3}{48}-\frac{1}{4} \pi  \log ^2(2)$$

Enjoy !

Comment: Thank you. I've got the same by using CAS, but I'm looking for a closed-form not in term of $_4F_3$, because my original problem was to get a closed form for this $_4F_3$, what you also found. Thank you anyway, maybe someone else could give us another one.

Comment: There is only one thing I should tell you : good luck ! I shall wait for answers. Cheers

Comment: @user153012 You probably know that [you can express](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/920995/19661) this hypergeometric term via the imaginary part of a trilogarithm of a complex argument...

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yes, thank you. I know it and I have already an answer there. So to tell the truth that was the "more" original problem. I thought, that if we could solve this integral, then we could answer also for Lucian's question. By the way [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/937487/153012) is also related, so we could tell that this three problem is equivalent, and there are at least two more problem on math.se, which get an answer by answering one of this three.

Answer (score 5):

**My attempt.** This is by no means closer to the answer, but I want to address several equivalent forms that might be helpful for future calculations.

First, from [Landen's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) of the following form

$$ \mathrm{Li}_2(z) = -\mathrm{Li}_2\left(-\frac{z}{1-z}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\log^{2}(1-z), \quad z \notin [1, \infty)$$

we observe that

\begin{align*}
I
&= -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \left\{ \mathrm{Li}_2\left(-\frac{x}{1-x}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\log^{2}(1-x) \right\} \, dx \\
&= -\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{2\mathrm{Li}_2 (t) + \log^{2}(1-t)}{2\sqrt{1-2t}(1-t)} \, dt
\tag{1}
\end{align*}

By noting that

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}\right) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-2t}(1-t)}, $$

integration by parts and the substitution $x = (1-2t)^{-1/2}$ shows that (1) is equal to

\begin{align*}
I
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}\right) \frac{2\log(1-t)}{t(t-1)}  \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{8x \arctan x}{1 - x^4} \log \left( \frac{1+x^2}{2x^2} \right) \, dx \tag{2}
\end{align*}

The following observation

$$ \Re \log \left(\frac{1+ix}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\log \left( \frac{1+x^2}{2} \right)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\Im \log \left(\frac{1+ix}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \arctan x $$

somehow seems to suggest complex-analytic approach, but I have not been successful with such approaches so far. Next, from the following simple formula

$$ \log \left( \frac{1+x^2}{2x^2} \right) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dy} \log \left( \frac{y^2+x^2}{y^2 + 1} \right) \, dy $$

the integral (2) can be further decomposed into the following form

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{16xy \arctan x}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(x^2+y^2)} \,dxdy. \tag{3} $$

Simple calculation shows that

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{16xy}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(x^2+y^2)} \,dxdy = 2\zeta(2), $$

so I suspect that the situation in (3) is not that bad.

Answer (score 4):

From writing $$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=-\int_0^1\frac{x\ln u}{1-xu}du$$

It follows that

$$-I=-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_0^1\ln u\left[\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1-ux)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\right]du$$

$$=\int_0^1\ln u\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}-\frac1u\right)+\frac{\sin^{-1}(u)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right]du$$
$$=\frac{\pi}2\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{u}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-1\right)du+\int_0^1\frac{\ln u\sin^{-1}(u)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$

For the first integral, let $u^2\to u$ first then apply integration by parts, we obtain

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{u}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-1\right)\ du=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^1\ln^2u\ du\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}}-1\right)du\\=-\frac{\pi}{32}\int_0^1\ln^2u (1-u)^{-3/2}du=-\frac{\pi}{32}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\alpha^2}\lim_{\alpha\ \mapsto1}\text{B}\left(\alpha,-\frac12\right)\\=-\frac{\pi}{32}\left(\frac23\pi^2-8\ln^22\right)=\boxed{\frac{\pi}4\ln^2(2)-\frac{\pi^3}{48}}\, .$$

The second integral is already calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431753/is-there-a-closed-form-for-int-01-frac-lnx-sin-1xx-sqrt1-x2dx/3431858#3431858)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x) \sin^{-1}(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\boxed{4 \operatorname{Im} \operatorname{Li}_3(1+\mathrm{i}) -\frac{3 \pi^3}{16} -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln^2(2)}  \, .$$

Collecting the boxed results we get

> $$I= \frac{5 \pi^3}{24}-4 \operatorname{Im} \operatorname{Li}_3(1+\mathrm{i})  \, .$$

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a different perspective by exploiting the Fourier series.

**A solution by Cornel Ioan Valean (in large steps)**

In the book **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023)**, at the end of section **6.49**, two other Fourier series are announced, which can be derived, as explained, by using a strategy from **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**. It is about

$$\tan(x)\log(1-\cos(x))=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_0^1 t^{n/2-1} \frac{1-t}{1+t}\textrm{d}t \right)\sin(n x), \ 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2};$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(\cos(x))=\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{1}{2} \log^2(2)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \left(\int_0^1 t^{n/2-1}\frac{1-t}{1+t} \textrm{d}t\right)\cos(nx),\ 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

**Proof:** The following result, $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \tanh(x)e^{-n x}\textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\psi\left(\frac{n+2}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)-\frac{2}{n}\right)$, can be extracted from **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**, page $243$, and by the variable change $e^{-2y}=t$ it is immediately clear that $\displaystyle 2 \int_0^{\infty} \tanh(y)e^{-n y}\textrm{d}y=\int_0^1 t^{n/2-1}\frac{1-t}{1+t} \textrm{d}t$. Upon multiplying both sides by $\sin(n x)$ and making the summation from $n=1$ to $\infty$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\int_0^1 t^{n/2-1}\frac{1-t}{1+t} \textrm{d}t\right) \sin(n x)=2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \tanh(y) \sin(n x)e^{-n y}\textrm{d}y$$
$$=2 \int_0^{\infty} \tanh(y) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n x)e^{-n y}\textrm{d}y=\sin(x) \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(y)}{\cosh(y)-\cos(x)}\textrm{d}y$$
$$
\overset{1/\cosh(y)=t}{=}-\tan(x) \int_0^1 \frac{-\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x) t}\textrm{d}t=-\tan(x) \log(1-\cos(x) t)\biggr|_{t=0}^{t=1}$$
$$=-\tan(x) \log(1-\cos(x)),$$
which leads to the first Fourier series. In the calculations, the well-known Fourier series, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^n \sin(nx)=\frac{p\sin(x)}{1-2 p\cos(x)+p^2}, \ |p|<1$, is employed.

To get the second Fourier series, we exploit the first Fourier series, where we replace $x$ by $y$, and then integrate from $y=0$ to $y=x$, and further use that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\int_0^1 t^{n/2-1} \frac{1-t}{1+t}\textrm{d}t \right)\overset{t=u^2}{=}2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\int_0^1 u^{n-1} \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\textrm{d}u \right)=2\int_0^1 \frac{(1-u^2)\log(1-u)}{u(1+u^2)} \textrm{d}u=2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)}{u} \textrm{d}u}_{\displaystyle -\pi^2/6}-4 \int_0^1 \frac{u\log(1-u)}{1+u^2} \textrm{d}u=-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{8},$ where the second integral is $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{u\log(1-u)}{1+u^2} \textrm{d}u=\frac{1}{8}\log^2(2)-\frac{5}{96}\pi^2$, given in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**, page $8$.

So, integrating from $x=0$ to $x=\pi/2$ using the second Fourier series, letting $t\mapsto t^2$, and further exploiting the parity, we get that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\operatorname{Li}_2(\cos(x))\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac{1}{4} \log^2(2)\pi+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \left(\int_0^1 t^{n-1}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \textrm{d}t\right)\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac{1}{4} \log^2(2)\pi-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 t^{2n-2}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \textrm{d}t\right)u^{2n-2}\log(u)\textrm{d}u$$
$$=\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac{1}{4} \log^2(2)\pi+2\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \left(\frac{ (1+u^2) \log (u)}{(1-u^2) (1+ u^2 t^2)}-2\frac{ \log (u)}{(1+t^2)(1-u^2)}\right)\textrm{d}t\right)\textrm{d}u$$
$$=\pi \underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log(u)}{1-u^2}\textrm{d}u}_{\displaystyle \text{well-known}- \pi^2/8}-2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(u)\log(u)}{u}\textrm{d}u}_{\displaystyle \text{well-known}- \pi^3/32}+2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(u)\log(u)}{1+u}\textrm{d}u$$
$$-2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(u)\log(u)}{1-u}\textrm{d}u$$
$$=\frac{\pi^3}{96}+\frac{3}{8}\log^2(2) \pi-4 \Im\biggr\{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\biggr \},$$
where we also used that $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\arctan(u)\log(u)}{1+u}\textrm{d}u=\frac{\log(2)}{2}G-\frac{\pi^3}{64}$, with solutions that may be found in [Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \log x}{1+x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842284/evaluating-int-01-frac-arctan-x-log-x1xdx) and **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**, pages $140$-$142$, and $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\arctan(t) \log(t)}{1-t}\textrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}\log(2)G-\frac{\pi}{16}\log^2(2)-\frac{\pi^3}{16}+2\Im\biggr\{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\biggr\},$ which is given and derived in **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023)**, pages $784$-$785$, that is obtained by using $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\log(1+a t)\log(t)}{1-t}\textrm{d}t=-\zeta(2)\log(1+a)-\frac{1}{3}\log^3(1+a)-\log(1+a)\operatorname{Li}_2(-a)+\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)+2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{1+a}\right),$ which is evaluated by differentiation.

**End of story**

Answer (score 3):

Following Anastasiya-Romanova's approach, we have:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n x\,dx =\frac{\pi}{16}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n^2 4^n}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}n(2n-1)^2}\tag{1}$$
where:
$$ S_1 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n^2 4^n} = \zeta(2)-2\log^2 2 \tag{2}$$
and the second sum is the problematic one, leading to a value for a hypergeometric function $\phantom{}_4 F_3$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}S_2 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}n(2n-1)^2} &=& -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\arcsin x}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\log x\,dx\\&=&-2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}\log\sin\theta\,d\theta. \tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$

However, since the Fourier cosine series of $\log\sin\theta$ is well-known:
$$\log\sin\theta = -\log 2-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2n\theta)}{n}\tag{4} $$
we just need to compute the Fourier cosine series of $\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}$. Since the Fourier sine series of the triangle wave is given by:
$$ \theta = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(2n\theta) \tag{5}$$
by exploiting $\frac{\sin(2n\theta)}{\sin\theta}=2\left(\cos\theta+\cos(3\theta)+\ldots+\cos((2n-1)\theta)\right)$ we have:

$$\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}=2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\sum_{n\geq k}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\right)\cos((2k-1)\theta)\tag{6}$$
so, at least in principle, $S_2$ is computable through a Fourier-analytic approach, by exploiting:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos((2n-1)\theta)\cos(2m\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{(2n-1)(-1)^m}{4m^2-(2n-1)^2}.\tag{7}$$

It is also interesting to notice that the last integral appearing in $(3)$ is very similar to the one appearing in this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168209/closed-form-of-int-0-pi-2x-cot-leftx-right-cos-leftx-right-log-left/1168221#1168221), but the latter is way easier to compute since in the Fourier cosine series of $\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}\,\cos^2\theta$ there are only "even cosines".

Comment: Can you please tell me how you obtained $(2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Using Maple I am obtaining

$$1+\frac{\pi }{16}{\ _4F_3(1,1,1,3/2;\,2,2,2;\,1)}+\frac{\sqrt {\pi }}{8}
G^{4, 1}_{4, 4}\left(-1\, \Big\vert\,^{1, 5/2, 5/2, 5/2}_{2, 3/2, 3/2, 1}\right)
$$

and a numerical approximation is

$$1.3913063720392030337$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you get this? Because the numerical value has just 6 correct digits. Maybe because of this hard Meijer G? After 2000 sec of evaluation in Maple I wasn't able to get a result of this Meijer G. WolframAlpha also runs out of time. Are you sure that is this a correct result? By the way
$${_4F_3}\left(\begin{array}c 1,1,1,\frac32\\2,2,2\end{array}\middle|\,1\right)=\frac{\pi^2}3-\ln^24$$
So you can [simplify](http://goo.gl/kg0m1g) your expression.

Answer (score 1):

Another one... replacing the Meijer G in Juan's answer
$$
{\mbox{$_4$F$_3$}(1/2,1/2,1,1;\,3/2,3/2,3/2;\,1)}+
\frac{\pi \,
{\mbox{$_4$F$_3$}(1,1,1,3/2;\,2,2,2;\,1)}}{16}
\\
\approx 1.3913072075067666818109648381255138301541952863
$$
and with user's comment
$$
{\mbox{$_4$F$_3$}(1/2,1/2,1,1;\,3/2,3/2,3/2;\,1)}+\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac{\pi (\log 2)^2}{4}
$$
agreeing with Claude.

Comment: There are a couple of hypergeometric functions like that one with various parameters shifted by $\pm1$ that have closed forms in terms of the Catalan constant. Maybe something can be made of this and simplify the term through contiguous relations?