# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}(2H_{2k}+H_k)=\frac{\pi^3}{32}-2G\ln2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

How to prove

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}(2H_{2k}+H_k)\stackrel ?=\frac{\pi^3}{32}-2G\ln2,$$
>   where $G$ is the Catalan's constant.

**Attempt**

For the first sum,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}H_{2k}=\Re\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{(k+1)^2}H_{k}\right\},$$
which can be evaluated by using the formula in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/604316/394456):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}\, x^n=\zeta(3)+\frac{\ln(1-x)^2\ln(x)}{2}+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x),$$
but we cannot apply the similar approach to the second sum 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}H_k.$$
Then, I tried to write the sum as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\int_0^1\frac{2x^{2k}+x^k-3}{x-1}~\mathrm dx$$
and it become more complicated.

**Edit:**

Are we able to evaluate the sum *directly* (avoid calculating integrals and  polylogs as much as possible)? The integral given by @Jack D'Aurizio is a bit complicated ([see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2972249/394456)).

Comment: Please look e.g. at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917154/looking-for-closed-forms-of-int-0-pi-4-ln2-sin-x-dx-and-int-0-pi-4/920224#920224 , where the second series is discussed as a side effect (constant $K$ , answer of *Lucian*) .

Comment: @user90369 Thank you for the [link](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse13.php#x15-12200013)!

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 4):

The series involving $H_k$ and $H_{2k}$ can be studied in a similar way: since
$$ \frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n\geq 1} H_n x^{n} $$
we have $ \frac{-\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} = \sum_{n\geq 1} H_n(-1)^n x^{2n} $ and
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}H_k = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x^2)\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
boils down to
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4} -2\log(\cos\theta) \log(\tan\theta)\,d\theta $$
which is simple to tackle through [well-known Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos). It equals

$$ -\frac{\pi^3}{64}-K\log(2)-\frac{\pi}{16}\log^2(2)+2\,\text{Im}\,\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\approx -0.07355395672853217. $$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
S&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{(2n+1)^2}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&=2\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i)^nH_{n}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
&=S_1+S_2-\frac{\pi^3}{16}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Using [the generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number): $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$
then 
\begin{align}
S_1&=2\Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_3(i)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)+\ln(1-i)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-i)+\frac12\ln(i)\ln^2(1-i)\right)\\
&\boxed{S_1=-2\Im\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)-G\ln2-\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^22}
\end{align}

$$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{(2n+1)^2}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)\ln x}{1+x^2}\ dx$$
The last integral is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211825)

$$\boxed{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)\ln x}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac3{32}\pi^3+\frac{\pi}8\ln^22-G\ln2+2\text{Im}\operatorname{Li_3}(1-i)=S_2}$$
Plugging $S_1$ and $S_2$ in $(1)$, we get $$\color{blue}{S=\frac{\pi^3}{32}-2G\ln2}$$

note that we used:
$$\ln(i)=\frac{\pi}{2}i$$
$$\ln(1-i)=\frac12\ln2-\frac{\pi}{4}i$$ 
$$\operatorname{Li_2}(1-i)=\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\ln2+G\right)i$$
which give us:
$$\ln(i)\ln^2(1-i)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2-\left(\frac{\pi^3}{32}-\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^22\right)i$$
$$\ln(1-i)\operatorname{Li_2}(1-i) =-\frac{\pi}{4}G-\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln2-\left(\frac12\ln2G+\frac{\pi^3}{64}+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^22\right)i$$

Answer (score 2):

this summation also has some relationship with integral identity, which asked almost the same time, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006106/an-amm-like-integral-int-01-frac-arctan-xx-ln-frac1x231x2dx), rewrite as

$$\frac3{2} \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x^2)}{x} \mathrm{d}x} = \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x)}{x} \mathrm{d}x}$$

given some famous series

$$\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}}$$

$$\frac1{2} \arctan x \ln (1+x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{2n}}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}}$$

on the left

$$\frac3{2} \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x^2)}{x} \mathrm{d}x} = 3\int_{0}^{1} {\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{2n}}{2n+1} x^{2n}} \>\mathrm{d}x} = 3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}}$$

on the right

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x)}{x} \mathrm{d}x}
& = \int_{0}^{1} {\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} x^{2n}\ln(1+x) \>\mathrm{d}x}\\
& = 2\ln2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{1+x^{2n+1}}{1+x}}\mathrm{d}x}\\
& = 2G\ln2 - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \int_{0}^{1} {\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {(-x)^k}}\mathrm{d}x}\\
& = 2G\ln2 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} {\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}}\\
& = 2G\ln2 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}(H_{n}-H_{2n+1})}
\end{aligned}$$

unscramble this identity

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}(H_{n}+3H_{2n}-H_{2n+1})} = -2G\ln2$$

or

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}(H_{n}+2H_{2n})} 
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}(H_{2n+1}-H_{2n})} - 2G\ln2\\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}} - 2G\ln2 = \frac{\pi^3}{32} - 2G\ln2
\end{aligned}$$

where you may need some particular values of [Dirichlet Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html).

Comment: very nice solution. (+1)