# Closed form for ${\large\int}_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, polylogarithm

This is a follow-up to my earlier question [Closed form for ${\large\int}_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{\sqrt{1-x+x^2}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918821/19661).

Is there a closed form for this integral?
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx\tag1$$

*Mathematica* and *Maple* cannot evaluate it directly. A numeric approximation for it is
$$I\approx-6.1665252325192513801994672415450909679747097867356795481...\tag2$$
(click [here](http://goo.gl/oFzjSP) to see more digits).

As I mentioned in the earlier question, *Mathematica* is able to find a closed form for a parameterized integral in terms of the [Appell hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x^a}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx\\=\frac1{a+1}F_1\left(a+1;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};a+2;(-1)^{\small1/3},-(-1)^{\small2/3}\right),\tag3$$
but taking a derivative from this looks a hard problem.

Comment: There is an equivalent rational integral, with no logs: $$\int_{1,1,1,1}^{\infty,\infty,\infty,\infty}\frac{96 \left(x_1^2 x_2^2+x_1 x_2+1\right) \left(x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2+x_1 x_2 x_3+1\right) \left(x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2 x_4^2+x_1 x_2 x_3
   x_4+1\right)}{x_1 \left(x_1+2\right) x_2 \left(x_1^3 x_2^3+2 x_1^2 x_2^2-x_1 x_2-2\right) x_3 \left(x_1 x_2 x_3-1\right)
   \left(x_1 x_2 x_3+1\right) \left(x_1 x_2 x_3+2\right) x_4 \left(x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4-1\right) \left(x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4+1\right) \left(x_1
   x_2 x_3 x_4+2\right)}$$

Comment: $$
2\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{3}\left(\,1 - t^{2} \over 1 + 2t\,\right)\,{1 \over 1 + 2t}\,{\rm d}t
$$

Comment: There is something bugging me here. Suppose that the approach to evaluate this integral is exactly the same as Mr. David & Tunk-Fey's answer in [the previous problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/918821/133248), then we must evaluate it the integral of [$\dfrac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)\ln(1+2x)}{1+2x}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28ln%281%2Bx%29%2Bln%281-x%29-ln%281%2B2x%29%29%5E3), [your bounty question before this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/921641/133248), meanwhile that integral has no a closed-form which mean this integral has no a closed-form too

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova Well, yes, it is possible to expand this integral to a sum of integrals, where one of the terms corresponds to my previous bounty question. But I still hope it might have a closed form. But even if it does not: Have you managed to evaluate all other terms? It's possible that "non-closed-form" part somehow cancels between them, leaving a closed form result for the integral in this question.

Answer (score 14):

I followed the same approach as I used in an answer to [another
question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921641), and
expanded your integral in multiple polylogarithms of weight 4, then
used some patterns in their values of weight 3 to guess terms that
might appear in the integral. Then I used an integer relation
algorithm to express your integral in terms of logs, zeta functions
and polylogarithms of small rational arguments with a tolerance of
about $10^{-200}$, and I found this value, which is correct to $3000$
digits.

There are $27$ polylogarithm terms there in total, and while I managed
to simplify them somewhat, I never quite managed to evaluate some of them
except by an integer relation algorithm.

Here it is:
$$\textstyle\def\Li{\mathrm{Li}}
-6 \Li_2(\frac{1}{3}) \zeta (2)+27 \Li_4(\frac{3}{4})+36 \Li_4(\frac{2}{3})-4 \Li_4(\frac{1}{2})-18 \Li_4(\frac{1}{3})-\frac{9}{2} \Li_4(\frac{1}{4})+6 \Li_2(\frac{1}{3}){}^2+6 \Li_2(\frac{1}{3}) \log ^2 3+24 \Li_2(\frac{1}{3}) \log ^2 2-48 \Li_3(\frac{2}{3}) \log3+96 \Li_3(\frac{2}{3}) \log2-48 \Li_3(\frac{1}{3}) \log3+72 \Li_3(\frac{1}{3}) \log2-24 \Li_2(\frac{1}{3}) \log2 \log3+78 \zeta (3) \log3-142 \zeta (3) \log2-\frac{151}{4} \zeta (4)-69 \zeta (2) \log ^2 3-122 \zeta (2) \log ^2 2+192 \zeta (2) \log2 \log3+\frac{73}{4} \log ^4 3+\frac{89}{6} \log ^4 2-70 \log2 \log ^3 3-56 \log ^3 2 \log3+93 \log ^2 2 \log ^2 3
$$

Here is the equivalent Mathematica expression to save people typing:

```
(-151*Pi^4)/360 - (61*Pi^2*Log[2]^2)/3 + (89*Log[2]^4)/6 + 32*Pi^2*Log[2]*Log[3] -  56*Log[2]^3*Log[3] - (23*Pi^2*Log[3]^2)/2 + 93*Log[2]^2*Log[3]^2 - 70*Log[2]*Log[3]^3 +  (73*Log[3]^4)/4 - Pi^2*PolyLog[2, 1/3] + 24*Log[2]^2*PolyLog[2, 1/3] -  24*Log[2]*Log[3]*PolyLog[2, 1/3] + 6*Log[3]^2*PolyLog[2, 1/3] + 6*PolyLog[2, 1/3]^2 +  72*Log[2]*PolyLog[3, 1/3] - 48*Log[3]*PolyLog[3, 1/3] + 96*Log[2]*PolyLog[3, 2/3] -  48*Log[3]*PolyLog[3, 2/3] - (9*PolyLog[4, 1/4])/2 - 18*PolyLog[4, 1/3] - 4*PolyLog[4, 1/2] +  36*PolyLog[4, 2/3] + 27*PolyLog[4, 3/4] - 142*Log[2]*Zeta[3] + 78*Log[3]*Zeta[3]
```

Comment: With all due respect, Sir, I don't think this is a proper way to answer this problem. I find an answer that comes from (human) mind is full of fascinating insights rather than output of machine. Please don't consider my comment as a rude expression Mr. Kirill but in my opinion, Mathematica & Maple, cs have ruined the art of solving integral & series like Deep Blue has ruined the art of playing chess. I hope someone here will come with legit proof for evaluating this integral. Peace... (>‿◠)✌

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova Don't be a Luddite :) Machines are very important tool to generate conjectures and verify manual computations. Many important known results would be very difficult or impossible to obtain without help of machines.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova While I sympathize with your point of view very much, I have to agree with Vladimir here. Part of being a good mathematician is making the best of the tools allotted to you, and this problem just looks too massive to be reasonably tackled by hand.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov No, I'm not trying to be a Luddite. My point is where is the art of math if its problems i.e. the four color theorem or Riemann hypothesis is solved by a machine? Um, maybe I'm just a conservative being. I still rely on machines to do lots things in my life though.

Comment: @DavidH You said too massive? How about this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/918821/133248? Still thinking too massive to be reasonably tackled by hand? You just *looks* the problem but not trying to solve it because you assume it's too massive to be reasonably tackled by hand. Or you're just unwilling to make the answer, I presume. (︺︹︺)

Comment: Somebody went too far here. I could imagine how hard work was it. Sadly there are two things, that maybe we'll never know. First: Is this really a correct answer of not? Second: What are the numbers behind the polylogarithm terms?

Comment: @user153012 What do you mean by "the numbers behind"?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Exact values of these polylogarithms.