# Integral $\int_0^1\frac{x^{42}}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}}\operatorname d \!x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Could you please help me with this integral?
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{42}}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}} \operatorname d \!x$$

---

Update: [user153012](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/153012/user153012) posted a result given by a computer that contains scary Appel function, and [Cleo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/97378/cleo) gave much simpler closed forms for powers $n=42,\,43$. I am looking for a way to prove those forms. I also would like to find a more general result that would work for arbitrary integer powers, not just $42$.

Comment: not sure if you're looking for a closed form but wolfram alpha gives .0237565. Given the high exponent of the numerator, if an approx is ok, you can say that your integral is approximately $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{42}}{x^2} = \int_0^1 x^{40}$ which is easy to integrate and gives 0.02439024.

Comment: You can integrate it using mathematical software, but the result is in terms of elliptic integrals...

Comment: It looks like if we replace $42$ with any other positive integer power $n$, we will always get one of the two forms given by Cleo (the first form with elliptic integrals for even $n$, and the second form with $\ln3$ for odd $n$), only the rational coefficients will be different for each $n$. Now we need to find a systematic way to compute those rational coefficients, and to prove this conjecture.

Comment: I think there also might be a closed form (without Appel function) for half-integer powers, but I could not find it yet.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov In odd case the $\log_2$ of the denomiator of the $\operatorname{abs}$ valued coefficients of $\ln3$ are in order $1, 4, 8, 11, 16, 19, 23, 26, 32, 35, 39, 42, 47, 50, 54, \dots$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Odd case**: The change of variables $x^2=t$ transforms the integral into
$$\mathcal{I}_{2n+1}=\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n+1}dx}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}}=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{t^ndt}{\sqrt{t^2-t+1}}$$
Further change of variables $t=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\left(s-\frac1s\right)$ allows to write $t^2-t+1=\frac3{16}\left(s+\frac1s\right)^2$ and therefore gives an integral of a simple rational function of $s$:
$$\mathcal{I}_{2n+1}=\frac12\int_{1/\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}\left[\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\left(s-\frac1s\right)\right]^n\frac{ds}{s}.$$

**Even case**: To demystify the result of Cleo, let us introduce
$$\mathcal{K}_n=\mathcal{I}_{2n}=\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}dx}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}}=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{t^{n-\frac12}dt}{\sqrt{t^2-t+1}}.$$
Note that 
$$\mathcal{K}_{n+1}-\frac12\mathcal{K}_n=\frac12\int_0^1 t^{n-\frac12}d\left(\sqrt{t^2-t+1}\,\right)=\frac12-\left(n-\frac12\right)\left(\mathcal{K}_{n+1}-\mathcal{K}_{n}+\mathcal{K}_{n-1}\right),$$
where the second equality is obtained by integration by parts. This gives a recursion relation
$$\left(n+\frac12\right)\mathcal{K}_{n+1}=n\mathcal{K}_{n}-\left(n-\frac12\right)\mathcal{K}_{n-1}+\frac12,\qquad n\geq1.$$
It now suffices to show that 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{K}_0&=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}}=\frac12\mathbf{K}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right),\\
\mathcal{K}_1&=\int_0^1\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}}=
\frac12\mathbf{K}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)-\mathbf{E}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)+\frac12.
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh. You've deleted the nice hypergeometric expression. :\ Isn't there a recursion for the odd case with some $\ln 3$ term? Really nice approach by the way.

Comment: @user153012 Thanks! One can obtain a recursion relation in the odd case in a completely similar way (integrating once by parts).

Comment: Can we use your $\mathcal{K}_n$ to evaluate this integral: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/918821/133248?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova I don't think so but who knows...

Answer (score 13):

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{42}}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}}dx=\frac{250\,351\,656\,060\,403}{1\,955\,894\,551\,246\,350}\\-\frac{25\,556\,904\,389\,521}{391\,178\,910\,249\,270}{\bf K}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)+\frac{29\,595\,166\,842\,073}{977\,947\,275\,623\,175}{\bf E}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\right),$$

where ${\bf K}(x)$ and ${\bf E}(x)$ are complete [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ kind.

---

You might be also interested to know that
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{43}}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+1}}dx=\frac{10\,495\,168\,793\,593}{86\,586\,540\,687\,360}-\frac{98\,084\,055\,671}{1\,099\,511\,627\,776}\ln3.$$

Answer (score 4):

*Mathematica* and *Maple* could solve this integral in term of [elliptic integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegral.html). Cleo's answer is a simplification of them.

If you prefer there is an other closed form in term of [Appell $F_1$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html).

$$I(a,n)=\int_0^1\frac{x^{a}}{\sqrt[n]{x^4-x^2+1}}\,dx = \frac{1}{1+a} F_1\left(\frac{1+a}{2},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{3+a}{2},(-1)^{1/3},-(-1)^{2/3}\right),$$
where $\Re(a)>-1.$

Your case is $I(42,2)$.

Comment: Do you know how exactly one can get Cleo's simplification from your result?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov I have limited knowledge about Appell $F_1$ function. I know just about [this connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Special_cases) between Appell $F_1$ and elliptic integrals.